# IntelliJ - Coding style

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sorry for the rather broad question, but how do I set IntelliJ to wrap long method calls like this:

[image: Style]

The style by having methods aligned with each other on new lines.

This is what happens after building the project/reopening IntelliJ:
[image]

Comment: `Code` -> `Format`?

Comment: I know. - Just what settings I need to change? I've played around but can't find out what one.

Comment: It's formatted as it should be, your right parenthesis at first row goes behind maxium length of line, either increase the length of your lines in code styling  either move `TimeRewards` to a new line, either extract a variable. Don't write code in single line, it's hard to read even if you declare one use variable.

Comment: @deathangel908 I'm wanting the .replace methods to be on separate lines aligned with each other as shown in the first picture - nothing is on one line. Although it is building to the 2nd picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works ok in my case, even if a line is bigger than the limit (after aplying reformatting):

[image]

This is the default behaviour (at least in Idea 15.0.1). If I were you, I would reset code styling settings (previously saved it) and start applying your changes one by one, until you find what's up.

FYI here's my settings that should work in your case as well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, here is what did it for me:

Comment: **Method call arguments** > Do not wrap & all false (couldn't edit previous comment)